# How to use a dict returned by a decorator as a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I am working on developing a flask app using `flask-restx`. In there, I would like to decorate the routes with a decorator named `cognito_check_groups` that checks the token, verifies it, and returns the claims.

I would like to know is there a way I can save the returning `claims` as a variable so that I can use its content further

My code:

```
def cognito_check_groups(groups: list):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            _cognito_check_groups(groups)
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

def _cognito_check_groups(groups: list):

    token = None
    if 'x-access-token' in request.headers:
        token = request.headers['x-access-token']

    if not token:
        return abort(
            401,
            'Missing token'
        )

    headers = jwt.get_unverified_headers(token)
    kid = headers['kid']
    
    key_index = -1
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        if kid == keys[i]['kid']:
            key_index = i
            break
    if key_index == -1:
        print('Public key not found in jwks.json')
        return False

    public_key = jwk.construct(keys[key_index])
    message, encoded_signature = str(token).rsplit('.', 1)
    decoded_signature = base64url_decode(encoded_signature.encode('utf-8'))
    
    if not public_key.verify(message.encode("utf8"), decoded_signature):
        print('Signature verification failed')
        return False
    print('Signature successfully verified')
    
    claims = jwt.get_unverified_claims(token)
    return claims
```

I have used the decorator as follows:

```
@crud_ns.route("/insert")
class InsertVendor(Resource):
    @crud_ns.doc(
        "Insert data into the DB",
        responses={
            200: "Values returned",
            400: "Validation Error",
            401: "Not authorized",
            409: "Conflct"
        },
    )
    @crud_ns.doc(security='apikey')
    @crud_ns.expect(crud_insert_parser, validation=True)
    @cognito_check_groups(['admin'])
    def post(self):
        args = crud_insert_parser.parse_args()
        return Insert.insert(**args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although i dont know much about Flask, usually you could something like this:

```
def cognito_check_groups(groups: list):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            claims = _cognito_check_groups(groups)
            # add claims to kwargs!
            kwargs.update({'claims': claims})
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

...
@cognito_check_groups(['admin'])
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    claims = kwargs.get('claims', {})
    args = crud_insert_parser.parse_args()
    return Insert.insert(**args)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion and it gives the following error `TypeError: post() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType`

Comment: @reinhardt: Updated, we cannot update `**kwargs` on the fly :)